# Click button on wordpress login page

Tags: powershell, button, authentication, submit

I have a problem to click the login button on the following page:

https://community.theme.co/wp/wp-login.php

I have tried to click the button with code below:

```
$submitButton = $ie.document.getElementById("wp-submit").Click(); 
foreach ($element in $submitButton)
{
    if ($element.Name -eq "wp-submit") {
        $element.Click()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think checking ie object's busy property might fix it.

```
$url= "https://community.theme.co/wp/wp-login.php"
$ie = new-object -ComObject "internetexplorer.application"
$ie.Navigate2($url)
$ie.Visible =$true
while($ie.Busy){
start-sleep 10
}

$submitButton = $ie.document.getElementById("wp-submit").click();
```

could not confirm as i don't have any valid credential but i think the click was happening